# What are the most common failure modes of Solid State Relays?

Tags: solid-state-relay

Doing an FMEA and this question came up, for both AC and DC SSRs

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Yes, but is there any failure commonality? For example, do they tend to fail off, or on

Comment: It depends if it is MOSFET, BJT, IGBT, SCR, TRIAC and who makes it and if the load is Capacitive, Inductive, and exceeds rating for ESD, PLT, Pd, T, V, I etc and cause of fault. Short Cct, normal use? human error, poor process controls, bad design etc . This is why fine print says... not responsible for Liability for loss or damage resulting from any reliance on the Information or use of it (including liability)

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 So, no generic failure modes then...

Comment: consider case by case for each root cause

Comment: Overcurrent tends to fuse semi's into shorts until the fuse blows open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK lets simplify this question....

Failure modes are....

1. Fail Open... Output can no longer be switched closed.
2. Fail Closed.. Output can no longer be switched open.
3. Catches Fire.. Device continues to operate but gets too hot and ignites. Will be followed by either mode 1 or mode 2 if there is anything left once you put the fire out.

Which particular mode will occur is application and device specific and is a matter of probability. Operating the device outside it's specified ratings will 
significantly increase the probability of failure, however, operating it well within those limits will not prevent it's eventual failure.

Generally fail open or fail closed is hard to be sure about. The best you can state is the device is more likely to fail one way or the other under normal or extraordinary load conditions. But both modes will have a finite probability of occurring for that particular device.

As such, when designing critical systems where you need to be sure the output enters a certain state when a failure occurs, additional circuits and methods are required.

Answer (score 1):

It is like what is first failure mode on all cars.

The Modes depend on Root Causes; Bad design margin for application, bad solder process with environmental stress, poor OEM quality controls (Qualification Test verification)

Use historical data only for each source and P/N then verify Design and Process with  a good DVT & PVT test plan.  Otherwise low confidence in your results in poor estimates.

If you need to design a circuit with likely potential for stuck ON switch then you need to do by a redundant safety switch means.